# Forms not working in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently i am working on forms but when i run my code ,i am getting the following error

```
 No provider for ControlContainer ("
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          [ERROR ->]<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
            <div class="form-group">
  "): TablesBasic@112:10
No provider for NgControl ("       <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">FirstName:</label>
```

My component,

```
import { Component,ViewChildren,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { emailValidator } from './validator'
declare var Messenger: any;
@Component({
  selector: '[tables-basic]',
 templateUrl: './tables-basic.template.html'
})
export class TablesBasic implements OnInit {
  form:FormGroup;
  students:any;
  emailerror:any;
  firstnameerror:any;
  phoneerror:any;
  constructor(public http: Http,public fbld: FormBuilder) {
this.form = fbld.group({
            accountname: ['', Validators.required],
            lastname: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', emailValidator],
            phone: ['',  Validators.required]
})

    }
```

My template,

```
 <div class="modal-body">
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">FirstName:</label>
          <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['accountname']" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
         <span *ngIf="!form.controls['accountname'].valid" >
                                    <p class="error">{{firstnameerror}}</p>
                                </span>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">LastName:</label>
          <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['lastname']" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['email']" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

                                 <span *ngIf="!form.controls['email'].valid" >
                                    <p class="error">{{emailerror}}</p>
                                </span>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
          <input type="text" [formControl]="form.controls['phone']" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
            <span *ngIf="!form.controls['phone'].valid" >
                                    <p class="error">{{phoneerror}}</p>
                                </span>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

I had used this forms many times before but i didnot encounterd this kind of error ,can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

My ngModule,

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { removeNgStyles, createNewHosts, createInputTransfer } from '@angularclass/hmr';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import {ModalModule} from "ng2-modal";

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';
import { ROUTES } from './app.routes';
// App is our top level component
import { App } from './app.component';
import { APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS } from './app.resolver';
import { AppState, InteralStateType } from './app.service';
import { AppConfig } from './app.config';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  ...APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS,
  AppState,
  AppConfig
];

type StoreType = {
  state: InteralStateType,
  restoreInputValues: () => void,
  disposeOldHosts: () => void
};

/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
    ModalModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef, public appState: AppState) {}

  hmrOnInit(store: StoreType) {
    if (!store || !store.state) return;
    console.log('HMR store', JSON.stringify(store, null, 2));
    // set state
    this.appState._state = store.state;
    // set input values
    if ('restoreInputValues' in store) {
      let restoreInputValues = store.restoreInputValues;
      setTimeout(restoreInputValues);
    }

    this.appRef.tick();
    delete store.state;
    delete store.restoreInputValues;
  }

  hmrOnDestroy(store: StoreType) {
    const cmpLocation = this.appRef.components.map(cmp => cmp.location.nativeElement);
    // save state
    const state = this.appState._state;
    store.state = state;
    // recreate root elements
    store.disposeOldHosts = createNewHosts(cmpLocation);
    // save input values
    store.restoreInputValues  = createInputTransfer();
    // remove styles
    removeNgStyles();
  }

  hmrAfterDestroy(store: StoreType) {
    // display new elements
    store.disposeOldHosts();
    delete store.disposeOldHosts;
  }

}
```

Comment: show your ngModule configuration..

Comment: micronyks,edited my code.